# Replace a string in a file with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, replace, gruntjs

I use the [md5 grunt task](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-md5) to generate MD5 filenames. Now I want to rename the sources in the HTML file with the new filename in the callback of the task. I wonder what's the easiest way to do this.

Comment: I wish there was a renamer and replace-in-file combination, which would both rename the files, and search/replace any reference for those files as well.

Comment: @Brain2000 I had the same need, so I created a CLI tool named **rev-web-assets** to hash the filenames and update their references.  It's intended for use in **npm** scripts and is on GitHub: [rev-web-assets](https://github.com/center-key/rev-web-assets)

Answer (score 442, accepted):

You could use simple regex:

```
var result = fileAsString.replace(/string to be replaced/g, 'replacement');
```

So...

```
var fs = require('fs')
fs.readFile(someFile, 'utf8', function (err,data) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }
  var result = data.replace(/string to be replaced/g, 'replacement');

  fs.writeFile(someFile, result, 'utf8', function (err) {
     if (err) return console.log(err);
  });
});
```

Comment: Sure, but do I have to read the file replace the text and then write the file again, or is there an easier way, sorry I'm more of a frontend guy.

Comment: Maybe there is a node module to achieve this, but i'm not aware of it. Added a full example btw.

Comment: @Zax: Thanks, I'm surprised this 'bug' could survive so long ;)

Comment: sorry as i know utf-8 support many language like: vietnamese, chinese...

Comment: If your string appearance multiple times in your text it will replace only the first string it finds.

Comment: @eltongonc Why doesn't [the `/g` flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/global) handle that? `"12131415".replace(/1/g, "0")` gives `'02030405'`, for instance.

Comment: @ruffin my bad, I didn't notice the regex

Answer (score 122):

Since replace wasn't working for me, I've created a simple npm package [replace-in-file](https://www.npmjs.com/package/replace-in-file) to quickly replace text in one or more files. It's partially based on @asgoth's answer.

**Edit (3 October 2016)**: The package now supports promises and globs, and the usage instructions have been updated to reflect this.

**Edit (16 March 2018)**: The package has amassed over 100k monthly downloads now and has been extended with additional features as well as a CLI tool.

Install:

```
npm install replace-in-file
```

Require module

```
const replace = require('replace-in-file');
```

Specify replacement options

```
const options = {

  //Single file
  files: 'path/to/file',

  //Multiple files
  files: [
    'path/to/file',
    'path/to/other/file',
  ],

  //Glob(s) 
  files: [
    'path/to/files/*.html',
    'another/**/*.path',
  ],

  //Replacement to make (string or regex) 
  from: /Find me/g,
  to: 'Replacement',
};
```

Asynchronous replacement with promises:

```
replace(options)
  .then(changedFiles => {
    console.log('Modified files:', changedFiles.join(', '));
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Error occurred:', error);
  });
```

Asynchronous replacement with callback:

```
replace(options, (error, changedFiles) => {
  if (error) {
    return console.error('Error occurred:', error);
  }
  console.log('Modified files:', changedFiles.join(', '));
});
```

Synchronous replacement:

```
try {
  let changedFiles = replace.sync(options);
  console.log('Modified files:', changedFiles.join(', '));
}
catch (error) {
  console.error('Error occurred:', error);
}
```

Comment: Great and easy to use turn-key module. Used it with async/await and a glob over quite a large folder and it was lightning fast

Comment: Will it be able to work with file sizes greater then 256 Mb since i read somewhere that string limit in node js is 256 Mb

Comment: I believe it will, but there is also a work in progress to implement streaming replacement for larger files.

Comment: nice, I found and used this package (for its CLI tool) before I ever read this SO answer. love it

Comment: there is tiny problem with that implementation, what if i want to replace { KEY } all the time at Angular build process, Regexp replaces string only once and that's it developer reaches dead-end. This would work for only one shot

Comment: Excellent! This works super fast and easy!

Comment: Absolutely wonderful code, and fittings explanations to boot!

Answer (score 41):

Perhaps the "replace" module ([www.npmjs.org/package/replace](http://www.npmjs.org/package/replace)) also would work for you.  It would not require you to read and then write the file.

Adapted from the documentation:

```
// install:

npm install replace 

// require:

var replace = require("replace");

// use:

replace({
    regex: "string to be replaced",
    replacement: "replacement string",
    paths: ['path/to/your/file'],
    recursive: true,
    silent: true,
});
```

Comment: Do you know how can filter by file extension in paths? something like paths: ['path/to/your/file/*.js'] --> it doesn't work

Comment: You can use node-glob to expand glob patterns to an array of paths, and then iterate over them.

Comment: This is nice, but has been abandoned. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/31040890/1825390 for a maintained package if you want an out-of-the-box solution.

Comment: There's also a maintained version called [node-replace](https://github.com/raphamorim/node-replace); however, looking at the code base neither this nor replace-in-file _actually_ replace text in the file, they use `readFile()` and `writeFile()` just like the accepted answer.

Comment: The library works fine but it does not have Typescript support

Answer (score 31):

You can also use the 'sed' function that's part of ShellJS ...

```
 $ npm install [-g] shelljs


 require('shelljs/global');
 sed('-i', 'search_pattern', 'replace_pattern', file);
```

Full documentation ...

- [ShellJS - sed()](https://documentup.com/shelljs/shelljs#sedoptions-search_regex-replacement-file_array)
- [ShellJS](https://documentup.com/shelljs/shelljs)

Comment: this seems to be the cleanest solution :)

Comment: `shx` lets you run from npm scripts, ShellJs.org recommended it. https://github.com/shelljs/shx

Comment: I like this too. Better an oneliner, than npm-module, but surveral lines of code ^^

Comment: Importing a third party dependency is not the cleanest solution.

Comment: This won't do multilines.

Answer (score 12):

If someone wants to use promise based 'fs' module for the task.

```
const fs = require('fs').promises;

// Below statements must be wrapped inside the 'async' function:
const data = await fs.readFile(someFile, 'utf8');
const result = data.replace(/string to be replaced/g, 'replacement');
await fs.writeFile(someFile, result,'utf8');
```

Answer (score 5):

You could process the file while being read by using streams. It's just like using buffers but with a more convenient API.

```
var fs = require('fs');
function searchReplaceFile(regexpFind, replace, cssFileName) {
    var file = fs.createReadStream(cssFileName, 'utf8');
    var newCss = '';

    file.on('data', function (chunk) {
        newCss += chunk.toString().replace(regexpFind, replace);
    });

    file.on('end', function () {
        fs.writeFile(cssFileName, newCss, function(err) {
            if (err) {
                return console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log('Updated!');
            }
    });
});

searchReplaceFile(/foo/g, 'bar', 'file.txt');
```

Comment: But... what if the chunk splits the regexpFind string? Doesn't the intention fail then?

Comment: That's a very good point. I wonder if by setting a `bufferSize` longer than the string that you're replacing and saving the last chunk and concatenating with the current one you could avoid that problem.

Comment: Probably this snippet should also be improved by writing the modified file directly to the filesystem rather than creating a big variable as the file might be larger than available memory.

Comment: @JaakkoKarhu I made an npm package that keeps old chunks in memory in case the string spans multiple chunks. It's called [`stream-replace-string`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stream-replace-string#how-it-works). It doesn't work with regexs, but it is an efficient solution when just finding strings.

Answer (score 4):

On Linux or Mac, keep is simple and just use sed with the shell. No external libraries required. The following code works on Linux.

```
const shell = require('child_process').execSync
shell(`sed -i "s!oldString!newString!g" ./yourFile.js`)
```

The sed syntax is a little different on Mac. I can't test it right now, but I believe you just need to add an empty string after the "-i":

```
const shell = require('child_process').execSync
shell(`sed -i "" "s!oldString!newString!g" ./yourFile.js`)
```

The "g" after the final "!" makes sed replace all instances on a line. Remove it, and only the first occurrence per line will be replaced.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on @Sanbor's answer, the most efficient way to do this is to read the original file as a stream, and then also stream each chunk into a new file, and then lastly replace the original file with the new file.

```
async function findAndReplaceFile(regexFindPattern, replaceValue, originalFile) {
  const updatedFile = `${originalFile}.updated`;

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const readStream = fs.createReadStream(originalFile, { encoding: 'utf8', autoClose: true });
    const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(updatedFile, { encoding: 'utf8', autoClose: true });

    // For each chunk, do the find & replace, and write it to the new file stream
    readStream.on('data', (chunk) => {
      chunk = chunk.toString().replace(regexFindPattern, replaceValue);
      writeStream.write(chunk);
    });

    // Once we've finished reading the original file...
    readStream.on('end', () => {
      writeStream.end(); // emits 'finish' event, executes below statement
    });

    // Replace the original file with the updated file
    writeStream.on('finish', async () => {
      try {
        await _renameFile(originalFile, updatedFile);
        resolve();
      } catch (error) {
        reject(`Error: Error renaming ${originalFile} to ${updatedFile} => ${error.message}`);
      }
    });

    readStream.on('error', (error) => reject(`Error: Error reading ${originalFile} => ${error.message}`));
    writeStream.on('error', (error) => reject(`Error: Error writing to ${updatedFile} => ${error.message}`));
  });
}

async function _renameFile(oldPath, newPath) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.rename(oldPath, newPath, (error) => {
      if (error) {
        reject(error);
      } else {
        resolve();
      }
    });
  });
}

// Testing it...
(async () => {
  try {
    await findAndReplaceFile(/"some regex"/g, "someReplaceValue", "someFilePath");
  } catch(error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
})()
```

Comment: This does not handle the case where the text that `regexFindPattern` matches is split between two chunks.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into issues when replacing a small placeholder with a large string of code.

I was doing:

```
var replaced = original.replace('PLACEHOLDER', largeStringVar);
```

I figured out the problem was JavaScript's special replacement patterns, described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter). Since the code I was using as the replacing string had some `$` in it, it was messing up the output.

My solution was to use the function replacement option, which DOES NOT do any special replacement:

```
var replaced = original.replace('PLACEHOLDER', function() {
    return largeStringVar;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

ES2017/8 for Node 7.6+ with a temporary write file for atomic replacement.

```
const Promise = require('bluebird')
const fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require('fs'))

async function replaceRegexInFile(file, search, replace){
  let contents = await fs.readFileAsync(file, 'utf8')
  let replaced_contents = contents.replace(search, replace)
  let tmpfile = `${file}.jstmpreplace`
  await fs.writeFileAsync(tmpfile, replaced_contents, 'utf8')
  await fs.renameAsync(tmpfile, file)
  return true
}
```

Note, only for smallish files as they will be read into memory.

Comment: No need for `bluebird`, use native `Promise` and [util.promisify](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original).

Comment: @FranciscoMateo True, but beyond 1 or 2 functions promisifyAll is still super useful.

Answer (score 1):

This may help someone:

This is a little different than just a global replace

from the terminal we run
`node replace.js`

replace.js:

```
function processFile(inputFile, repString = "../") {
var fs = require('fs'),
    readline = require('readline'),
    instream = fs.createReadStream(inputFile),
    outstream = new (require('stream'))(),
    rl = readline.createInterface(instream, outstream);
    formatted = '';   

const regex = /<xsl:include href="([^"]*)" \/>$/gm;

rl.on('line', function (line) {
    let url = '';
    let m;
    while ((m = regex.exec(line)) !== null) {
        // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
        if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
            regex.lastIndex++;
        }
        
        url = m[1];
    }

    let re = new RegExp('^.* <xsl:include href="(.*?)" \/>.*$', 'gm');

    formatted += line.replace(re, `\t<xsl:include href="${repString}${url}" />`);
    formatted += "\n";
});

rl.on('close', function (line) {
    fs.writeFile(inputFile, formatted, 'utf8', function (err) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
    });

});
}


// path is relative to where your running the command from
processFile('build/some.xslt');
```

This is what this does.
We have several file that have xml:includes

However in development we need the path to move down a level.

From this

```
<xsl:include href="common/some.xslt" />
```

to this

```
<xsl:include href="../common/some.xslt" />
```

So we end up running two regx patterns one to get the href and the other to write
there is probably a better way to do this but it work for now.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Nomaly, I use `tiny-replace-files` to replace texts in file or files. This pkg is smaller and lighter...
https://github.com/Rabbitzzc/tiny-replace-files

```
import { replaceStringInFilesSync } from 'tiny-replace-files'

const options = {
  files: 'src/targets/index.js',
  from: 'test-plugin',
  to: 'self-name',
}

# await
const result = replaceStringInFilesSync(options)
console.info(result)
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30702529)

Answer (score 0):

I would use a duplex stream instead. like documented here [nodejs doc duplex streams](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_implementing_a_transform_stream)

> A Transform stream is a Duplex stream where the output is computed in
>   some way from the input.

Answer (score 0):

`<p>Please click in the following {{link}} to verify the account</p>`

```
function renderHTML(templatePath: string, object) {
    const template = fileSystem.readFileSync(path.join(Application.staticDirectory, templatePath + '.html'), 'utf8');
    return template.match(/\{{(.*?)\}}/ig).reduce((acc, binding) => {
        const property = binding.substring(2, binding.length - 2);
        return `${acc}${template.replace(/\{{(.*?)\}}/, object[property])}`;
    }, '');
}
```

```
renderHTML(templateName, { link: 'SomeLink' })
```

for sure you can improve the reading template function to read as stream and compose the bytes by line to make it more efficient

Answer (score 0):

Having the oppurtunity to handle file system in nestJs, I had this kind of requirement
since there is no replace method defined by default, you can simply save a new file while keeping the same id or key :

```
 async updateFile(
    file: any,
    id:string
  ): Promise<string> {
    try {

       const filePath = path.join(your directory path, id);
       await fs.promises.writeFile(filePath, file.buffer);
       return id

    } catch (error) {
      throw new InternalServerErrorException();
    }
}
```