# How to replace all html code of the <body> tag with NodeJS?

Tags: html, node.js, filesystems

Based on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14181136/3363138 I did the corresponded modifications:

```
var fs = require('fs')
var desired_code = '<div>Desired Code</div>'

fs.readFile(file.html, 'utf8', function (err,data) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }

  //Here I need to load all the body tag content, but how?
  var result = data.replace(<body>html tags to be replaced</body>, desired_code);

  fs.writeFile(file.html, result, 'utf8', function (err) {
     if (err) return console.log(err);
  });
});
```

On this function I need to load all the body tag content, but how can I do it?

```
var result = data.replace(<body>html tags to be replaced</body>, desired_code);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change something in html code that is String, I see two options now :

- You write a Regex expression for that (easy, fast, but less clean and secure) ;
- You use a html parser like cheerio.js, change your node "body" and stringify (more complicated but more secure and clean).

For the first option, something like :
`data = data.replace(/<body>(.*)<\/body>/, '<div>Hello world</div>');`

For the second option, something like :

`parsed = cheerio.parse(data);
parsed.find('body').html('<div>Hello world</div>');
data = cheerio.html();`

Comment: Plus one but I disagree with the regex option

Comment: Thanks. This regex works for me: /<body>(.|\n)*?<\/body>/