# rewriting a file content into json prepared

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a file called "file.php" contained lines like this (not only) :

```
 ...
 define("META_PAGE_BRAND_HOME_TITLE","esta es la Marca");
 define("META_PAGE_BRAND_HOME_DESCRIPTION","Conoce nuestra Marca y empieza con la web ");
 define("META_PAGE_BRAND_HOME_KEYWORDS","Marca Logo Mision");
 ...
```

I would like to get this:

```
{
 "meta_page_brand_home_title":"esta es la Marca",
 "meta_page_brand_home_description":"Conoce nuestra Marca y empieza con la web ",
 "meta_page_brand_home_keywords":"Marca Logo Mision"
 }
```

I would like to rewrite those only the lines beginning with "define(" into the console or a new file , caps in the first part should be lowercase . I know I should do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14177087/replace-a-string-in-a-file-with-nodejs) but I'm not that sharp to achieve so.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step that you'd have to do is to actually read the contents of your file, which can be done using [`fs.readFile()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v7.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_file_options_callback).

```
fs.readFile('path/to/file.php', function(err, fileContents) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    // `fileContents` will then contain the contents of your file.
});
```

Once you have the contents of your file, you will then need to find the `define()` calls using regex and use it inside the code before:

```
var regex = /define\((".*?"), *(".*?")\)/g;
var match = regex.exec(fileContents);
// `fileContents` contains the contents of your file.

while(match) {
    // match[1] will contain the first parameter to the "define" call
    // match[2] will contain the second parameter to the "define" call
    // use match[1] and match[2] however you want, like log it to the console:
    console.log(match[1].toLowerCase() + ':' + match[2] + ',');

    // Look for the next match
    match = regex.exec(fileContents);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to achieve what you are trying to do with an advanced text editor like [Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com/3).

With Sublime you will be able to do multiple select on

> define(

using a method method here: https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/multiple_selection_with_the_keyboard.html

Once you've got that you can remove all those lines.

You can do the same with

> );

And replace it with the

> ,

as requried.

Further, Sublime will allow you to change the case of selected words to all lower case, as you are required.