# Replace multiple strings in a file using nodejs

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, fs, newman

I have a json file in which I want to replace two words with two new words using fs of node js. I read the solution to a similar query on [Replace a string in a file using nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14177087/replace-a-string-in-a-file-with-nodejs). Then I tried the following code snippet but it replaces only a single word. I need to run it multiple times to replace multiple words.

Here is the code snippet:

```
var fs = require('fs')
fs.readFile('C:\\Data\\sr4_Intellij\\newman\\Collections\\api_collection.json', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }
  var result1 = data.replace(/{{Name}}/g, 'abc');
  var result2 = data.replace(/{{Address}}/g, 'xyz');
  var arr1 = [result1,result2]
  console.log(arr1[0]);

  fs.writeFile('C:\\Data\\sr4_Intellij\\newman\\Collections\\api_collection.json', arr1, 'utf8', function (err) {
     if (err) return console.log(err);
  });

});
```

Comment: javascript does not support recursive matching for regexp natively, maybe you want to use a library for that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do the second `replace` on the result of the first replace. `data` isn't changed by `replace`; `replace` *returns* a new string with the change.

So:

```
var result = data.replace(/{{Name}}/g, 'abc')
                 .replace(/{{Address}}/g, 'xyz');
```

...then write `result` to the file.

Alternately, and this particularly useful if it's a large file or you  have lots of different things to replace, use a *single* `replace` with a callback:

```
var replacements = Object.assign(Object.create(null), {
    "{{Name}}": "abc",
    "{{Address}}": "xyz"
    // ...and so on...
});

var result = data.replace(/{{[^}]+}}/g, function(m) {
    return replacements[m] || m;
});
```

Or with a `Map`:

```
var replacements = new Map([
    ["{{Name}}", "abc"],
    ["{{Address}}", "xyz"]
    // ...and so on...
]);

var result = data.replace(/{{[^}]+}}/g, function(m) {
    return replacements.get(m) || m;
});
```

Comment: Hi Crowder, one more question: Can we replace these strings in multiple files at at a time ? Like writing into multiple files at a time. Thanks for your insights into this.

Comment: @SauravRath: Not *at the same time* (unless you spawn [child processes](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process) to do it), but you certainly can in a loop. Beware the [closures in loops problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example).

Comment: nice solutions. Specifically I like that `.replace.replace` one. Thanks for the answer.