# Replace a line in txt file using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs, writefile, appendfile

I am trying to simply replace a line in a text file using JavaScript.

The idea is:

```
var oldLine = 'This is the old line';
var newLine = 'This new line replaces the old line';
```

Now i want to specify a file, find the `oldLine` and replace it with the `newLine` and save it.

Anyone who can help me here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace a string in a file with nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14177087/replace-a-string-in-a-file-with-nodejs)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do it

```
var fs = require('fs')
fs.readFile(someFile, 'utf8', function (err,data) {

  var formatted = data.replace(/This is the old line/g, 'This new line replaces the old line');

 fs.writeFile(someFile, formatted, 'utf8', function (err) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
 });
});
```

Answer (score 17):

Just building on Shyam Tayal's answer, if you want to replace an entire line matching your string, and not just an exact matching string do the following instead:

```
fs.readFile(someFile, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
  let searchString = 'to replace';
  let re = new RegExp('^.*' + searchString + '.*$', 'gm');
  let formatted = data.replace(re, 'a completely different line!');

  fs.writeFile(someFile, formatted, 'utf8', function(err) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
  });
});
```

The 'm' flag will treat the ^ and $ meta characters as the beginning and end of each line, not the beginning or end of the whole string.

So the above code would transform this txt file:

```
one line
a line to replace by something
third line
```

into this:

```
one line
a completely different line!
third line
```