# How can I remove the content of txt file with JavaScript And put Another content in the same file (replace the content)

Tags: javascript

In fact I'v tried too many codes but it didn't work properly.
I want A javascript code to replace the content of TXT file.
All codes I got were for updating the content with the old data. 
Thanks

Comment: "In fact I'v tried too many codes but it didn't work properly" Care to share any of these attempts?

Comment: you can work with file system only in Node.js

Comment: with nodeJS file-io https://www.npmjs.com/package/files-io

Comment: maybe this helpful : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53446570/replace-a-line-in-txt-file-using-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace the contents of a file in node.js like so:

```js
const fs = require('fs');

fs.writeFile("message.txt", "new content", (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('The file has been saved!');
});
```

[docs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback)

It's not possible for code running in a browser, as this would constitute a major security risk.

Comment: Thank you so much but I'm trying to make a web app on my device only [without upload it to internet] is this methode suitable for my taget?

Comment: Does your app run in a web browser like Firefox, Chrome, or Internet Explorer?

Comment: Unfortunately No 

Comment: How do you run it then?

Comment: By node.js but that is NOT satisfying enough so I decided to use PHP server with JavaScript Ajax.