# Replace multiple strings in a text file with one string using javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, replace, writefile

I'm trying to replace  multiple strings in a text file with one string using javascript

I want those two strings "user" and "password" must be replaced with  'replace the string'
Anyone help me here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace a line in txt file using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53446570/replace-a-line-in-txt-file-using-javascript)

Comment: I tried this [Replace a line in txt file using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53446570/replace-a-line-in-txt-file-using-javascript) Replace a line in txt file using JavaScript.but it is only replacing only specific string not entire line.

for example. I wanted to replace entire line contains "user":"1232",
But it is replacing like this "replace the string" : "1232" not entire line.Anyh
 help here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to add to the previous replies, you can use [capture groups](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Groups_and_Ranges) to back reference parts of the matched text i.e.

if you search for "user"

```
let newText = yourText.replace(/^((\"user\")(:".*")(.*))$/gm, '"removed"$3$4' );
```

if you search for "1232"

```
let newText = yourText.replace(/^((\".*\")(:"1232")(.*))$/gm, '"removed"$3$4' );
```

Comment: can you please explain the. regex how it works?

Comment: var formatted = data.replace(/^((\"user\")(:".*")(.*))$/gm, 'This new line replaces the old line');
If i try the above .it will replace entire line "user":"1232" right?