# Nodejs script to uncomment some lines of code or replace a comment with contents from a file

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I am looking for a nodejs script that will replace the `IN` with the `OUT` below.

### IN

```
/* api_start ====
app.use('/api',require('./api/api'));
app.use('/sms',require('./api/sms'));
==== api_end */
```

or

```
// app.use('/api',require('./api/api'));
// app.use('/sms',require('./api/sms'));
```

---

### OUT

```
app.use('/api',require('./api/api'));
app.use('/sms',require('./api/sms'));
```

Basically just uncommenting those lines of code.

---

## or

just replace a comment like, `/* api_here */` with contents from a file which would contain the middle where from the `OUT` above (`api.js`).

## UPDATE

from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25072070/3066142

The following will work if i could just write the regex to recognize that line. Below is my attempt

```
// require:
var replace = require("replace");

// use:
replace({
    regex: "//\s+app\.use\('/api',require\('\./api/api'\)\);", // string to be replaced
    replacement: "test worked!!", // replacement string
    paths: ['dist/server.js'], // path/to/your/file'
    recursive: true,
    silent: true,
});
```

Comment: You might want to look into regexes. You can find documentation here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Comment: You might try using the [strip-comments](https://www.npmjs.com/package/strip-comments) npm package.

Comment: Amazingly enough, comments are a regular expression even though basically everything else in programming languages are not regular expressions.

Comment: I dont know regex well enough to write it myself. I think a solution to replace a comment with a file's contents like a template script would be the best solution

Comment: By the way, if you were to uncomment the first example you'd end up with `api_start ====
app.use('/api',require('./api/api'));
app.use('/sms',require('./api/sms'));
==== api_end` not `app.use('/api',require('./api/api'));
app.use('/sms',require('./api/sms'));`

Comment: see my update to the original question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

working codepen (including more block comments, etc.): https://codepen.io/Frederic-Klein/pen/KbXxeB?editors=0012

Example code for matching and replacing the given example using regular expressions with capturing `(...)` and non-capturing `(?:...)` groups for the replacements with inline explanations:

```
const content = `
/* api_start ====
app.use('/api',require('./api/api'));
app.use('/sms',require('./api/sms'));
==== api_end */
// app.use('/api',require('./api/api'));
// app.use('/sms',require('./api/sms'));
`;

const regex_block_comments = /^\/\*.*\n((?:app.*\n)*)(?:.*\*\/\n)/gm;
// match lines
// starting with /*
// having the following lines start with app, capture all those lines as one group ($1 reference)
// having a line ending with */ afterwards, as non-capturing group
// repeat globally (g) and match multiline (m) string

const regex_comment = /^\/\/\s*(app.*;\n)/gm;
// match lines
// starting with //
// ignore following whitespaces
// having text "app" afterwards, capture from app to line-ending as group ($1 reference)

const replacement = `$1`;

newcontent = content.replace(regex_block_comments,replacement);
newcontent = newcontent.replace( regex_comment,replacement);

// content after replacements
console.log(newcontent);
```

To learn more about regular expressions and for building your patterns I recommend https://regexr.com/ and https://regex101.com/.