# VSCode Extension API search and replace text in all files. (function of Ctrl+Shift+R)

Tags: typescript, vscode-extensions

I am trying to make an vscode extension which needs to alter some specific text in all the files the current root directory. [Invoke this method from extension code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFHtk.png)

How can i do that?

Comment: `workbench.action.replaceInFiles` just opens the panels, it doesn't actually replace. Is that what you want? If you want to actually replace, this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14177087/863110

Comment: yes i want to replace. But since this feature in already in vscode i wonder if there is any way to invoke that method from within the code without opening panel. I want to pass the text to be replaced as argument and that will replace in all the files in the root folder. Thanks a lot for your help  :)

Comment: I don't you can use it as it's an internal implementation. So I believe the other answer can help..